# X509Certificate - string name to OID in Java

Tags: java, security, x509certificate

How to get value from X509Certificate if I only know name of the field?
For example "CN" has OID "2.5.4.3", if I know get only string name how can I convert it to OID and get value from field?

How I can get numeric OID if I have only string name of OID?

Comment: The CN is in the subjectName as CN=. What does the OID have to do with it?

Comment: Hi, CN have OID represantation and we can get it by OID. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . In my case, I get only literal names and I know how to get value by OID, but I can't convert literal name to numeric OID. If think to do it with simple mappings, but it's not best solution and I don't think that Java doesn't implement something like this.

Comment: You have certificates with OIDs in them? In any case the mapping is fixed by RFCs and ISO standards, and are also given by your citation. You just need to construct a mapping table.

Comment: @EJP That's first time when I work with certificates, that's why I'm here. But when I get text representation I can see field keys like GIVENNAME, CN etc. But also I can get values with OID. As I know certificates standardized, in my case it's X509 and all X509 certs store information equally.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the problem. You have the names, you have their OIDs, what exactly is the difficulty? If you're asking whether Java provides a mapping, I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager{
private X509Certificate[] serverX509CertificateArray;
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
            //TODO xcs array include: OID,...
        this.serverX509CertificateArray = xcs;
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return this.serverX509CertificateArray;
    }
}
```

Code part:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] {new CustomX509TrustManager()}, new java.security.SecureRandom());
SSLSocketFactory ssf = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://www.facebook.com/").openConnection();

        conn.setSSLSocketFactory(ssf);
        conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String string, SSLSession ssls) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(1000 * 2);
        conn.connect();
        //READ HTML
        conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: This insecure code has nothing whatsoever to do with the question. It won't even work. The `getAcceptedIssuers()` method is called by the server, not by the client, so it has nothing to do with `checkServerTrusted()`, and certainly cannot rely on that being called first. And it is not permitted to return null. It's just nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

`X509ObjectIdentifiers.commonName` will give you the OID of the CN.

See: http://javadox.com/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.51/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/X509ObjectIdentifiers.html

This has all the X.509 defined OIDs, there are similarly named classes around for other well known ASN1 identifiers.